# How do I get a left join with a group by clause to return all the rows?

Tags: mysql, group-by, outer-join

I am trying to write a query to determine how much of my inventory is committed at a given time, i.e. current, next month, etc.

A simplified example:

I have an inventory table of items.  I have an offer table that specifies the customer, when the offer starts, and when the offer expires.  I have a third table that associates the two.

```
create table inventory
(id int not null auto_increment , name varchar(32) not null, primary key(id));

create table offer
(id int not null auto_increment , customer_name varchar(32) not null, starts_at datetime not null,  expires_at datetime, primary key (id));

create table items
(id int not null auto_increment, inventory_id int not null, offer_id int not null, primary key (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_item__offer FOREIGN KEY (offer_id)  REFERENCES offer(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_item__inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id)  REFERENCES inventory(id));
```

create some inventory

```
insert into inventory(name)
    values ('item 1'), ('item 2'),('item 3');
```

create two offers for this month

```
insert into offer(customer_name, starts_at)
    values ('customer 1', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')), ('customer 2', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'));
```

and one for next month

```
insert into offer(customer_name, starts_at)
    values ('customer 3', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01'));
```

Now add some items to each offer

```
insert into items(inventory_id, offer_id)
    values (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3);
```

What I want is a query that will show me all the inventory and the count of the committed inventory for this month.  Inventory would be considered committed if the starts_at is less than or equal to now, and the offer has not expired (expires_at is null or expires_at is in the future)

The results I would expect would look like this:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   | committed_inventory |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | item 1 |                   1 |
|  2 | item 2 |                   2 |
|  3 | item 3 |                   0 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query that I felt should work is:

```
SELECT inventory.id
     , inventory.name
     , count(items.id) as committed_inventory
  FROM inventory
  LEFT JOIN items
    ON items.inventory_id = inventory.id
  LEFT JOIN offer
    ON offer.id = items.offer_id
 WHERE (offer.starts_at IS NULL OR offer.starts_at <= NOW())
   AND (offer.expires_at IS NULL OR offer.expires_at > NOW())
 GROUP BY inventory.id, inventory.name;
```

However, the results from this query does not include the third item.  What I get is this:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   | committed_inventory |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | item 1 |                   1 |
|  2 | item 2 |                   2 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot figure out how to get the third inventory item to show.  Since inventory is the driving table in the outer joins, I thought that it should always show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `where` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT inventory.id
     , inventory.name
     , count(offers.id) as committed_inventory
  FROM inventory
  LEFT JOIN items
    ON items.inventory_id = inventory.id
  LEFT JOIN offer
    ON offer.id = items.offer_id and
       (offer.starts_at <= NOW() or
        offer.expires_at > NOW()
      )
 GROUP BY inventory.id, inventory.name;
```

The problem is that you get a matching offer, but it isn't currently valid.  So, the `where` clause fails because the offer dates are not `NULL` (there *is* a match) and the date comparison fails because the offer is not current ly.

Comment: This returns the third inventory item, but incorrectly gives a count of 1.  The third item is not committed in the current month.  What I want to return is zero committed_inventory for the third month.

Comment: @CharlieWhite . . . I changed the `count` to be on `offers.id`, which I think does what you want.

Comment: Very nice.  I thought about moving the where clause to the join, but out smarted myself. I've always used the join clauses to specify the fields in the join, and the where clause to filter results.  I guess I just didn't think it through all the way.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For item 3 the `starts_at` from `offer` table is set to March, 01 2014 which is greater than `NOW` so `(offer.starts_at IS NULL OR offer.starts_at <= NOW())` condition will skip the item 3 record

[**See fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af87d/6)